# Interpreting regression result with dependent variable is level variable while independent variable is percentage

Tags: regression, mixed-model, interpretation, regression-coefficients, percentage

If I have a model of level-percentage such as:

*Harvest(Y) = β0 + β1 GrowthPrice%(X1) + β2 GrowthCostIndex%(X2)*

Regression Result: Y = 43946.11 + 7498.16(X1) - 30585.34(X2)

The dependent variable (Y) is the harvest in ton (level variable), then is it right to interpret the model like level-log model? "One unit increase in X1 will increase the harvest by (7498.16/100) unit of Y"

or how should I interpret it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a linear model, an increase by 1 in one of the independent variables will increase the dependent variable by its corresponding beta. If your independent variables are percentages, than it would be correct to say
"An increase in X1 of one percentage point is associated with a harvest increase of β1" (mind the "associated", in your statement you are implicitly assuming a causal effect).

Comment: Also one should add "expected" or "on average", as there is variation, even though assumed to be random.

Comment: Thank you for your help!